# Fast converting raw files to pdf with watermark to swf

Tags: python, flash, pdf, hadoop, celery

I already had a script for converting raw files to pdf with watermark to swf. Tools I used are unoconv, python, celery and libreoffice. The problem is that it's slow for converting large files. I think the solution for this is splitting the pages and convert it on multiple celery worker or hadoop.

### Questions:

- My problem is that where should I start to make faster conversion of files?
- What library can I use to read the encrypted pdf by not decrypting the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your celery tasks so it can work in parallel and call them using [`group()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.group) function.

Comment: I already did that.  I think what I need is splitting the pages and convert it? what do you think?

Comment: Yes, but that's your task implementation. Probably you will have to add additional parameter where you can pass page numbers to parse.